# @input event not triggered in <q-option-group /> in quasar 2

Tags: vuejs3, quasar

here is my code

<q-option-group
dense
:options="deliveryOptions"
type="radio"
color="black"
@input="trigger(addressPreference)"
v-model="addressPreference"

/>

Answer (score 0):

You can use @update:

```
@update:model-value="trigger(addressPreference)"
```